# Ajax jquery php contact form

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, contacts

i am trying to get the message inside the (ack div) without refreshing the page I have following code

index.php
index page is the page which contain form and css file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>contact form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        background:#eee;}
    .errors{color:red;
            margin:4px;
            font-style:italic;
            }
    label{
        display:block;
        }

    #container{
        margin:auto;
        width:800px;
        padding:15px;
        background:white;
        border-radius:5px;
        }

    input[type=text], input[type=email]{
        width:200px;
        padding:5px;
        margin-right:4px;
        }                   
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="ack"> </div>

    <form id="contactform">
    <div>
    <label for="name">NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="email">EMAIL:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="JohnDoe@example.com" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="comment">MESSAGE:</label>
    <textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" />
    </form>
    </div><!---div container end here--->
    </body>
    </html> 

 function.js
 this file handles validation the part

    $(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            var emailReg = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/;
            var errors = false;
            var name = $('[name=name]').val();
            var email = $('[name=email]').val();
            var comment = $('[name=comment]').val();
            $('.errors').remove();
            if($("#name").val() == ""){
                $("#name").after("<span class= 'errors'> Missing Name </span>");
                errors = true;
                }
            if($("#email").val() == ""){
                $("#email").after("<span class= 'errors'> Missing Email </span>");
                errors = true;
                }else if(!emailReg.test($('#email').val())){
                    $("#email").after("<span class= 'errors'> Not valid Email </span>");
                    errors = true;
                    }
            if($("#comment").val() == ""){
                $("#comment").after("<span class= 'errors'> Missing Comment </span>");
                errors = true;
                }

            if(errors == true){
                return false;
                }else{
                    $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'test.php',
                data: input_data,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function( msg ){
                $("#ack").html(msg);
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#ack").html('ERROR!');
            }
    });  
     return true; 
    }
            });
        });

test.php

    <?php
     if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $errors = array();
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $emailReg = '/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/ ';

        if(!($name) || !($email) || !($comment)){
            if(!$name){
                $errors[]="Missing Name";
                }
            if(!$email){
                $errors[]="Missing Email";
                }
            if(!$comment){
                $errors[]="Missing Comment";
                }       
            }elseif(!preg_match($emailReg,$email)){
                $errors[] = "Not a valid email address";
                }else{

                    echo "Thanks for your email";
                    }
    }
    ?>

thanks



**************************************************************************************************

I have done the following change to the code, PHP works perfectly in this code, also the validation now the only problem is even though I insert all the valid entries it give me error! message inside the ack div tag(as per my requirment the message should come from test.php page, which is no error found) because of this code :
                         if(count($errors) == 0){
        $errors = "No errors found";
        }
```

---

```
    index.php

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>contact form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        background:#eee;}
    .errors{color:red;
            margin:4px;
            font-style:italic;
            }
    label{
        display:block;
        }

    #container{
        margin:auto;
        width:800px;
        padding:15px;
        background:white;
        border-radius:5px;
        }

    input[type=text], input[type=email]{
        width:200px;
        padding:5px;
        margin-right:4px;
        }                   
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/function.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="ack"> </div>

    <form id="contactform">
    <div>
    <label for="name">NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="email">EMAIL:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="JohnDoe@example.com" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <label for="comment">MESSAGE:</label>
    <textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" />
    </form>
    </div><!---div container end here--->
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

function.js
validation of function.js wroks perfectly

```
$(function(){
                $("#submit").click(function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
                    var emailReg = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/;
                    var errors = false;
                    var name = $('[name=name]').val();
                    var email = $('[name=email]').val();
                    var comment = $('[name=comment]').val();
                    $('.errors').remove();
                    if($("#name").val() == ""){
                        $("#name").after("<span class= 'errors'> Missing Name </span>");
                        errors = true;
                        }
                    if($("#email").val() == ""){
                        $("#email").after("<span class= 'errors'> Missing Email </span>");
                        errors = true;
                        }else if(!emailReg.test($('#email').val())){
                            $("#email").after("<span class= 'errors'> Not valid Email </span>");
                            errors = true;
                            }
                    if($("#comment").val() == ""){
                        $("#comment").after("<span class= 'errors'> Missing Comment </span>");
                        errors = true;
                        }
                        if(errors == true) {
               return false;
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: 'test.php',
                   data: $("#contactform").serializeArray(),
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function( msg ) {
                      $("#ack").html(msg);
                   },
                   error: function() {
                      $("#ack").html('ERROR!');
                   }

                });  
                $('#contactform').submit();
            }



                    });
                });
```

---

test.php

I have remove the submit from the post

```
<?php
 if($_POST) {
    $errors = array();
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $emailReg = '/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/ ';

    if(!($name) || !($email) || !($comment)){
        if(!$name){
            $errors[]="Missing Name";
            }
        if(!$email){
            $errors[]="Missing Email";
            }
        if(!$comment){
            $errors[]="Missing Comment";
            }       
        }elseif(!preg_match($emailReg,$email)){
            $errors[] = "Not a valid email address";
            }

        if(count($errors) == 0){
            $errors = "No errors found";
            }   else{
                $output = "";
                foreach($errors as $error){
                    $output .= "<p class ='output'>$error</p>";
                    }
                }
}
?>
```

Comment: you aren't preventing the default form submit when you do your ajax

Comment: this isn't an answer it is a comment and is certainly in context with your issue. A comment will NOT deter answers

Comment: I don't think you really understand how this site works. Why anyone would complain about comments that could benefit them is amazing

Comment: What is your actual problem? Validation failing unexpectedly? Ajax not firing? PHP not behaving as expected? Div not updating as expected? Page refreshing? If you give us a more specific question you will get a more specific answer? On a side note, get some manners and gratitude for complete strangers who are trying to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a couple of things going on here.

First you'll want to understand the difference between the submit button, and the form submission.

You will want to prevent the default behavior of the submit function, and you'll want to manually submit the form.

So:

```
$("#submit").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
```

will prevent the default behavior of the click for the submit button.

Now, the form won't submit when you click "submit".  You will want to pass on the information via the AJAX call.  So, in order to do this, you need to fill in the "input_data" variable that you're intent on using.

```
...
  if(errors == true) {
     return false;
  } else {
     input_data = {
        "name"   : name,
        "email"  : email,
        "comment": comment,
        "submit" : true
     }
    $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: 'test.php',
       data: input_data,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function( msg ) {
          $("#ack").html(msg);
       },
       error: function() {
          $("#ack").html('ERROR!');
       }
    });  
}
...
```

We had to add "submit" to the POST data, to make sure it works from the script.  Now, on the PHP side, you have to make sure that you're sending back JSON, since that's what your AJAX request is looking for.

```
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      $errors = array();
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $comment = $_POST['comment'];
      $emailReg = '/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/ ';

     if(!($name) || !($email) || !($comment)){
          if(!$name){ $errors[]="Missing Name"; }
          if(!$email){ $errors[]="Missing Email"; }
          if(!$comment){ $errors[]="Missing Comment"; }
          $json_response = json_encode($errors);
     } elseif(!preg_match($emailReg,$email)) {
        $errors[] = "Not a valid email address";
        $json_response = json_encode($errors);
     } else {
        $json_response = json_encode(array("Thanks for your email"));
     }
     echo $json_response;
  }
```

Comment: Even though your attitude sucks and you're an ungrateful ass, I'm going to post the answer for the benefit of other people out there.  Please see the edit.

Comment: @user3695704 please be more specific than "it still dosen't work". What, precisely, did not work?

Comment: I am sorry for my indicent behaviour my nervouness toward ajax has turn me into monster, I should'nt have lose my patience, sorry once again

Comment: Really appreciate the time which you given to solve the problem in this code, Finally it work Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestion of Tim I did the following change to the code and it worked
index.php
I have add the javascript function to the index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>contact form</title>
<style type="text/css">
body{
    background:#eee;}
.errors{color:red;
        margin:4px;
        font-style:italic;
        }
label{
    display:block;
    }

#container{
    margin:auto;
    width:800px;
    padding:15px;
    background:white;
    border-radius:5px;
    }

input[type=text], input[type=email]{
    width:200px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-right:4px;
    }                   
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
        var emailReg = /^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/;
        var errors = false;
        var name = $('[name=name]').val();
        var email = $('[name=email]').val();
        var comment = $('[name=comment]').val();
        $('.errors').remove();
        if($("#name").val() == ""){
            $("#name").after("<span class= 'errors'> Missing Name </span>");
            errors = true;
            }
        if($("#email").val() == ""){
            $("#email").after("<span class= 'errors'> Missing Email </span>");
            errors = true;
            }else if(!emailReg.test($('#email').val())){
                $("#email").after("<span class= 'errors'> Not valid Email </span>");
                errors = true;
                }
        if($("#comment").val() == ""){
            $("#comment").after("<span class= 'errors'> Missing Comment </span>");
            errors = true;
            }
if(errors == true) {
     return false;
  } else {
     input_data = {
        "name"   : name,
        "email"  : email,
        "comment": comment,
        "submit" : true
     }
    $.ajax({
       type: 'post',
       url: 'test.php',
       data: input_data,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function( msg ) {
          $("#ack").html(msg);
       },
       error: function() {
          $("#ack").html('ERROR!');
       }
    });  
}


        });
    });

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="ack"> </div>

<form id="contactform">
<div>
<label for="name">NAME:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="email">EMAIL:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="JohnDoe@example.com" />
</div>
<div>
<label for="comment">MESSAGE:</label>
<textarea name="comment" rows="10" cols="50" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SEND" id="submit" />
</form>
</div><!---div container end here--->
</body>
</html>
```

---

test.php

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $errors = array();
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $emailReg = '/^([a-z0-9_\.-]+)@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/ ';

    if(!($name) || !($email) || !($comment)){
        if(!$name){
            $errors[]="Missing Name";
            }
        if(!$email){
            $errors[]="Missing Email";
            }
        if(!$comment){
            $errors[]="Missing Comment";
            }
            $json_response = json_encode($errors);      
        }elseif(!preg_match($emailReg,$email)){
            $errors[] = "Not a valid email address";
            $json_response = json_encode($errors);
            }else{
                $json_response = json_encode("Thanks for your comment");
                }
                echo $json_response;


}
?>
```